# Magento 2 Category Field in Backend empty, Index Table wrong?

Tags: magento2, category-products, reindex, category-tree

I'm trying to add categories to my products via Admin UI but unfortunately, the field in the backend is empty and doesn't show my categories:
[image]
I've had this problem since some weeks, but usually it was fixed when I flushed the cache, but now I can't fix it again.

For this specific product, the database entries from the table `catalog_catgory_product` look like this:

[image]

When I look at the table `catalog_category_product_index`, the entries for this product are the following:

[image]

for every store, there's one of those entries, but all of these are with the `category_id` 2 instead of 7 and 9. 2 ist the "all products" category:
[image]

I guess these differences break the backend field, as it can't match the ids 2 and 7/9. What am I missing? 
I already tried rebuildung the indices `catalog_category_product` and `catalog_product_category`.

**Update:**
Found some differences in `vendor/magento/module-ui/view/base/web/js/form/element/ui-select.js`:
In my local installation where everything works, the variable `copyNodes` in the method `parseOptions()` has the following format:

[image]

In my production env where it doesn't work, the same variable looks like this:
[image]

Comment: When you say backend.. it seems to me you're wanting to do this via Direct SQL! Or is this attempting to update via Admin UI?

Comment: @MackieeE I'm trying to do it via Admin UI, sorry for the confusion. The printscreens are from the database because I'm trying to figure out what's going on. The problem is that the Select-Field for the categories is always empty as you see in the first image.

Comment: Any JS Errors on the admin UI Page?

Comment: No, unfortunately not. I updated the question with some strange differences I've found. Do you have an idea how this happens?

Comment: Did you find a solution to this? I have the same problem